# Is superposition theorem the only method to calculate the \$I_0\$ in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, superposition

When I learned the superposition theorem, the book provided this circuit to me, and taught me how to use the superposition theorem to find the value of \$I_0\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIYZE4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I want to ask that why should use the superposition theorem to find the \$I_0\$ in this circuit? Must we use the superposition theorem to find the \$I_0\$?

I mean, is the superposition theorem the only method to calculate the \$I_0\$? If I have no idea about superposition theorem, that is, f I don't know what the superposition theorem is, I don't know there is a method called superposition theorem which can be used to calculate the \$I_0\$ value. Can we still use other methods to calculate the \$I_0\$? If yes, can anyone show me how to calculate the \$I_0\$?

Comment: Superposition implies that you identify the independent sources in the circuit (6 V and the 4-mA current source) and alternately turn them off to determine \$I_0\$: turn the 6 V off (replace it by a short circuit) while the 4-mA I-source is alive: determine \$I_{01}\$ in this mode. Then bring the 6-V source back on and turn the 4-mA off (open circuit it) and determine \$I_{02}\$. The current you want is simply \$I_0=I_{01}+I_{02}\$. I like superposition because it often leads to simple intermediate circuits you can solve by inspection only (no equation).

Comment: Nodal analysis would work just fine. The big benefit of superposition is when you use both DC and AC sources in the same circuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *i want to ask that why should use the superposition theorem to find
>   the I0 in this circuit?must we use the superposition theorem to find
>   the I0?*

No, unless you are instructed to do so.

> *i mean is superposition theorem the only method to calculate the I0?*

And...

> *can we still use some methods to calculate the I0? if yes!can anyone show me how to calculate the I0?*

My natural instinct is to simplify....

So, I'd rearrange - the current source is attached to a grounded voltage source - that immediately allows it (the current source) to be moved directly across R3 - this simplifies any analysis because you can turn it into a voltage source of 48 volts in series with 12 kohm (R3).

I'd then rearrange V1, R1 and R2 into a 3 volt source in series with R1||R2 (= 6 kohm). It's simple math to see that the current through R4 flows right to left with a magnitude of 1.5 mA.

Drill down a bit more and the current though R2 is easily found (0.5 mA).

Simulation confirms: -

[image]

And, just in case anyone is perturbed by my suggested modification to split the current source from the voltage source and place it across R3: -

[image]

Then, convert I1 to a voltage source (I've called it V_I1 below) and rearrange the proper voltage source (V1), R1 and R2 into a source with a single resistor of 6 kohm (named R5) and it's really simple to find the current through R4.

[image]

As I said earlier, drilling down a little more finds I_0.

Comment: Nice solution, +1

Comment: thanks a lot,this answer really helps me a lot,however,i have a question about your equivalent circuit,can you tell me is my thinking right or wrong?https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495082/is-this-reason-why-we-can-let-the-current-source-be-attached-to-a-grounded

Comment: Ehm, isn't this possible **because** of the super position principle?? Do you have a "proof" (next to your *"natural instinc"*) this is different from applying the super position principle. (Not to critisize, I **instinctively** upvoted your answer as well and still support it).

Comment: Given that the analysis I did considers all energy sources simultaneously (albeit somewhat transposed), I don't see that it could be said that it is @Huisman

Comment: @Andyaka So, could you please prove/explain why your method is valid?

Comment: My method is simply to recognize basic relationships between voltage and current sources. If you asked me to prove that the resistance of parallel resistors was \$\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}}\$ each time I used it, nobody would be impressed. I've never thought it necessary to prove this because I thought it intuitive. Maybe I once learned it formally but i don't remember. Maybe I just became accustomed to it over time. Maybe present me with a scenario and I'll attempt a proof.

Comment: @Huisman it's like the old knotty problem of a single voltage source feeding an unbalanced Wheatstone bridge that has a bridging resistor taking an imbalance current. How do you find that imbalance current? In this example I split the supply into two supplies each feeding one bridge half and take it from there - would that be unusual to you? I mean I'm adding a new voltage source and breaking the bridge in half in order to solve the problem. It cannot be solved with superposition because there is only 1 source but, I see "my solution" as coming from the same "book" as the one above.

Comment: @Huisman I'm up for the challenge and I'm warming to the idea. Maybe I call it "intuitive" because I forgot where I learned it or that I forgot that I actually *DID* learn it!!! I certainly don't think it's a brand new method or one that hasn't been documented before (I'm sure of that).

Comment: @Huisman OK, it's called source splitting and is covered in [this document](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118844373.app5)